# What is a good number of wakeups per second?

Tags: google-chrome, battery, powertop

I currently am getting around 600 per second with just this one google chrome window and the terminal window running powertop--which seems too high (and I used to get about 1.5x more battery life out of this computer than I am now). If I open a couple more tabs, it justs to 3000. Can anyone advise me on what numbers I should be expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Running Ubuntu 18.04.1 Kernel 4.17.2-lowlatency i get **900** wakeups per second (feels high, how if found this question)

Using the utility powertop I enabled all the power saving tunables that do seem to extend my battery life a lot, it puts a lot of the hardware to sleep

Battery life estimate went from 3h to 5:33h, and the fan is now off.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 22.04 (Xubuntu distro), Kernel 5.15, AMD+Nvidia, Nvidia Driver 525.78.01, Lenovo Legion 5, Feb 2023.

While in firefox browser, typing this, powertop is reporting **2.5K wakeups/second**.

If I minimize firefox, and don't touch mouse/keyboard, wakeups can go down to 800-1k, more or less.

I have Slimbook Battery controller 4 installed (fancy frontend for TLP).
Can't honestly say any profile makes a huge difference to wakeups.
DOES make a difference in terms of CPU freq scaling (as tested while encoding some media with handbrake).

Battery life in powersave profile (slimbook), I can maybe get something like 3.5 hours of battery life?
Powertop pretty consistently reports +-20W power draw. RIGHT after a night in sleep mode, I got about 10-15W draw... until I started USING the laptop again.

This is super frustrating, since many persons report +-7 hours battery life on windows. I never gave windows a try, so can't confirm. Nobody reports actual workload while getting this battery life, so that is also a question.

Anyway, thought I'd add my data points, since I'm also trying to figure out what constitutes "good" values, as reported by powertop (and battery life).

EDIT:
Apologies, I only realized after posting this was tagged with Google Chrome.
But I will say that this is a complex topic, and Google Chrome (or any other single application) can't really be looked at isolation imho.
I've been googling HARD around this topic all week - it has been frustrating.